# ¿Por qué imprime sólo el último número?

Tags: javascript

¿Por qué me ocurre que sólo imprime el 9?

```js
// Simplex for loop 



for (var i =0; i<10; i++) {
  
  document.getElementById("for").innerHTML = i;
  
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    #for {width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: white; position: absolute;}
  </style>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="for"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Te está machacando el texto, así que solo te imprime el último

Comment: No te entendí G3l0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tu problema es que al hacer `innerHTML = i` sustituyes lo que hay antes en cada iteración del for. Añadiendo en lugar de reemplazando, debes solucionarlo.

```js
// Simplex for loop 



for (var i =0; i<10; i++) {
  
  document.getElementById("for").innerHTML += i + "<br>";
  
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    #for {width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: white; position: absolute;}
  </style>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="for"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah gracias ! , pero porqué por ejemplo al hacer eso sustituye el valor de i , y por ejemplo al hacer document.write, no se sustituye?

Comment: Porque `document.write` no es destructivo, simplemente añade el contenido al HTML. `innerHTML = algo` sustituye todo el HTML por lo que tu le digas. Si te ha servido la respuesta por favor pulsa la flecha arriba y marcala como aceptada si te ha solucionado la duda.

Comment: okey Pedro gracias, tendrás alguna documentación de esto por favor?

Comment: `document.write` https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp y `innerHTML` https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

Comment: @EduardoSebastian Si tu duda ha sido resuelta, marca la respuesta como aceptada para evitar que salga en el apartado preguntas sin responder.